# Changing a color of a Bulma button when clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bulma

I want to change the color of my Bulma button, in my Rails app. Those button are use to filter results on a search page.

So far i did the following, but it is not working the color is not changing:

```
<%= link_to request.params.merge(category: "9"), class: "button is-rounded", id: "ButtonId" do %>
                                <i class="fas fa-thermometer-full"></i><%= t "services.title" %>
                                <% end %>

<script>
$('#ButtonId').click(function() {
$(this).addClass('has-background-danger');
});
</script>
```

Comment: and ? what's the problem, what are you asking ?

Comment: Well, it is not working, i am not sure why the color don't change

Comment: Do you think it could be turbolinks issue ?

Comment: Is the CSS from the added class getting applied or overwritten?

Comment: no the class is not changing

Comment: Ok, not really sure what you mean, is the class `'has-background-danger'` getting added?

Comment: no 'has-background-danger' is not added to the button class

Comment: Inspect the button, does it have the id `ButtonId` on it (and make sure it is the only button with this id on the page too)

Comment: yes the button as the specific id and it is also the only one having it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214856/discussion-between-rockwell-rice-and-tomas).

Answer (score 0):

I was not charging Fontawesome correctly, the following solve my problem:

First,

```
  yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

After in app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
   import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
```

And in app/javascript/css/main.scss

```
 @import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';
```

Finally in app/javascript/packs/application.js, i removed

```
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```